# how to make one div scrollable out of 2 or more div

Tags: html, css

i have 3 `div` tags
and i want to make one div (of the 3) `scrollable`

I have tried `overflow:"auto"` in the `div` i want to make `scrollable`
and `overflow:"hidden"` in the `div tags` i **don't** want to make `scrollable`.
but this is not working.
should i fix the size of all `div`
following are two `div` which i **don't** want to make scrollable

`<div class="span4" style="overflow:hidden">
...
<\div>`

`<div class="span4" style="overflow:hidden">
...
<\div>`

and following `div` is i want to make `scrollable`

`<div class="span4" style="overflow:auto">
...
<\div>`

Comment: The third `div` now should be scrollable if it has a fixed or limited height: e. g. `height:300px;` or `max-height:300px;`.

Comment: worked. gave fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overflow: scroll or overflow-y: scroll to be explicit